# Reasoning in S5

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm currently working on implementing reasoning involving time.

Since **S5** (every world accessible from any other) is sufficient for what I'm trying to represent, I wanted to know what are the **techniques**  used for **reasoning** (satisfiability) on this kind of logic (tableau based, etc...).

What is an *algorithm* that can be used? Or do someone know about some *software reasoners* that can do these tasks already?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using S5 to reason about time? Generally [temporal logics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/) are quite different from S5. If you think of the modal logic "accessibility" relation as the "earlier than" relation (as I believe is pretty common) it's easy to see why S5 is a bad choice. Only future and present times are accessible (or, earlier than) to the present time.

Comment: Because I use it to distinguish between rigid and anti-rigid properties (in other words, temporal entities and *snapshot* entities). Therefore I don't really need to distinguish past and future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/tools/) you can find a number of modal logic theorem provers. You should be able to find something that works for you there under the heading "Accessible theorem provers".

If you're taking a course on modal logic, or really want to learn this stuff, I'd steer clear of automated theorem provers except maybe to double-check your own work. I'm a pretty big fan of the tableau style of proof that Priest employs in [*An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052179434X). The way he does the trees it is pretty algorithmic.

Feel free to leave a comment if you need any more info.

Comment: +1 for recommending to do the proofs by hand. In my experience, until you've read the manual of _insert your favorite automated theorem here_, configured it and learned how to use it, you could have proved the theorems by hand 10 times.

Comment: @Eric'3ToedSloth' Absolutely agree. Especially with a tableau system like Priest's, the proofs are fairly mechanical _without_ an automated theorem prover.